# SignalR integration with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, chat

I didn't find any link with proper explanation for integrate signalR in iOS. Please share your efforts if you have successfully integrated.
I have studied these links :   [link](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR)  [link](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC)

Comment: Depending on your particular use case, SignalR may not be a good fit for an iOS client (or indeed any mobile platform). The reason is that the client needs to open, and keep open, a network connection to the server, which will chew through the phone's battery. Push notifications are generally a better solution for mobile clients.

Comment: @PaulLalonde thank you